# Js setInterval for different paragraphs not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, setinterval

I want to run a different timer for each paragraph. But unfortunatly it works according to the last paragraph. The function should run separatly for each paragraph. Here is my code

```js
$(".set_timer").each(function() {
  setTimer($(this).data("created_time"), $(this));
});

function setTimer(dateStart, ele) {
  countDownDate = new Date(dateStart).getTime();

  x = setInterval(function() {
    // Get todays date and time
    now = new Date().getTime();
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    distance = countDownDate - now;
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    ele.html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      ele.html("TIMER COMPLETED");
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="set_timer" data-created_time="May 12, 2018 11:56:30"></p>
<p class="set_timer" data-created_time="May 10, 2018 11:56:30"></p>
<p class="set_timer" data-created_time="May 08, 2018 11:56:30"></p>
<p class="set_timer" data-created_time="Apr 10, 2018 11:56:30"></p>
<p class="set_timer" data-created_time="Jun 15, 2018 11:56:30"></p>
<p class="set_timer" data-created_time="Jul 13, 2018 11:56:30"></p>
```

Current Output:

459d 1h 15m 25s

459d 1h 15m 25s

459d 1h 15m 25s

459d 1h 15m 25s

459d 1h 15m 25s

It should be different according to the `created_time data` attribute

Comment: That's what happens when all your variables are global. Throw in some `var` keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `var` to `countDownDate = new Date(dateStart).getTime();`

so it will be

```
 var countDownDate = new Date(dateStart).getTime();
 .
 .
 .
```

Answer (score 2):

Its expected as all variables are defined in global scope. Define then in local scope.

```js
$(".set_timer").each(function() {
  setTimer($(this).data("created_time"), $(this));
});

function setTimer(dateStart, ele) {
  let countDownDate = new Date(dateStart).getTime();
  let x = setInterval(function() {
    // Get todays date and time
    let now = new Date().getTime();
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    let distance = countDownDate - now;
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    let days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    let hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    ele.html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      ele.html("TIMER COMPLETED");
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="set_timer" data-created_time="May 12, 2018 11:56:30"></p>
<p class="set_timer" data-created_time="May 10, 2018 11:56:30"></p>
<p class="set_timer" data-created_time="May 08, 2018 11:56:30"></p>
<p class="set_timer" data-created_time="Apr 10, 2018 11:56:30"></p>
<p class="set_timer" data-created_time="Jun 15, 2018 11:56:30"></p>
<p class="set_timer" data-created_time="Jul 13, 2018 11:56:30"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function setTimer(dateStart, ele) {
    countDownDate = new Date(dateStart).getTime();
    x = setInterval((function (countDownDate) {
            // Get todays date and time
           return function(){
                now = new Date().getTime();
                // Find the distance between now an the count down date
                distance = countDownDate - now;
                // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
                days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
                ele.html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");
                // If the count down is over, write some text 
                if (distance < 0) {
                    clearInterval(x);
                    ele.html("TIMER COMPLETED");
                }
           }
        })(countDownDate), 1000);
```

Comment: please add some explanation with your code. BTW +1 for the effort